# Copy table from one dataset to another in google big query

Tags: copy, google-bigquery

I intend to copy a set of tables from one dataset to another within the same project. I execute the code in Ipython notebook.

I get the list of table names to be copied in the variable “value” using the below code:

```
list = bq.DataSet('test:TestDataset')

for x in list.tables():
   if(re.match('table1(.*)',x.name.table_id)):
     value = 'test:TestDataset.'+ x.name.table_id
```

Then i tried using the “bq cp” command to copy table from one dataset to another. But I cannot execute the bq command in the notebook.

```
!bq cp $value proj1:test1.table1_20162020
```

Note:

I tried with bigquery command to check whether there is a copy command associated with it but could not find any.

Answer (score 10):

I have created following script to copying all the tables from one dataset to another dataset with couple of validation.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

projectFrom = 'source_project_id'
datasetFrom = 'source_dataset'

projectTo = 'destination_project_id'
datasetTo = 'destination_dataset'

# Creating dataset reference from google bigquery cient
dataset_from = client.dataset(dataset_id=datasetFrom, project=projectFrom)
dataset_to = client.dataset(dataset_id=datasetTo, project=projectTo)

for source_table_ref in client.list_dataset_tables(dataset=dataset_from):
    # Destination table reference
    destination_table_ref = dataset_to.table(source_table_ref.table_id)

    job = client.copy_table(
      source_table_ref,
      destination_table_ref)

    job.result()
    assert job.state == 'DONE'

    dest_table = client.get_table(destination_table_ref)
    source_table = client.get_table(source_table_ref)

    assert dest_table.num_rows > 0 # validation 1  
    assert dest_table.num_rows == source_table.num_rows # validation 2

    print ("Source - table: {} row count {}".format(source_table.table_id,source_table.num_rows ))
    print ("Destination - table: {} row count {}".format(dest_table.table_id, dest_table.num_rows))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the BigQuery API with Python, you can run a copy job:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#copyingtable

Copying the Python example from the docs:

```
def copyTable(service):
   try:
    sourceProjectId = raw_input("What is your source project? ")
    sourceDatasetId = raw_input("What is your source dataset? ")
    sourceTableId = raw_input("What is your source table? ")

    targetProjectId = raw_input("What is your target project? ")
    targetDatasetId = raw_input("What is your target dataset? ")
    targetTableId = raw_input("What is your target table? ")

    jobCollection = service.jobs()
    jobData = {
      "projectId": sourceProjectId,
      "configuration": {
          "copy": {
              "sourceTable": {
                  "projectId": sourceProjectId,
                  "datasetId": sourceDatasetId,
                  "tableId": sourceTableId,
              },
              "destinationTable": {
                  "projectId": targetProjectId,
                  "datasetId": targetDatasetId,
                  "tableId": targetTableId,
              },
          "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
          "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
          }
        }
      }

    insertResponse = jobCollection.insert(projectId=targetProjectId, body=jobData).execute()

    # Ping for status until it is done, with a short pause between calls.
    import time
    while True:
      status = jobCollection.get(projectId=targetProjectId,
                                 jobId=insertResponse['jobReference']['jobId']).execute()
      if 'DONE' == status['status']['state']:
          break
      print 'Waiting for the import to complete...'
      time.sleep(10)

    if 'errors' in status['status']:
      print 'Error loading table: ', pprint.pprint(status)
      return

    print 'Loaded the table:' , pprint.pprint(status)#!!!!!!!!!!

    # Now query and print out the generated results table.
    queryTableData(service, targetProjectId, targetDatasetId, targetTableId)

   except HttpError as err:
    print 'Error in loadTable: ', pprint.pprint(err.resp)
```

The `bq cp` command does basically the same, internally (you could call that function too, depending on what `bq` you are importing).

Comment: Thanks Felipe. But in my scenario, I have to copy multiple tables that starts with a same name but has different timestamps in the end. That was the reason i loop through the table list and get the list of tables that start with 'table1'

Comment: seems like something easy to automate with python and the provided code?

Comment: How does the bq cp command work between datasets? I only see an error message claiming the destination dataset doesn't exist, which is clearly wrong (I also see this in the console; both the destination dataset and the incorrect error).

Answer (score 5):

Assume you want to copy most tables, you can first [copy the entire BigQuery dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets), then delete some tables you don't want to copy.

The copy dataset UI is similar to copy table. Just click "copy dataset" button from the source dataset, and specify the destination dataset in the pop-up form. You can copy dataset to another project or another region. See screenshots of how to copy dataset below.

**Copy dataset button**

[image]

**Copy dataset form**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Now coping dataset feature available in **[BigQuery Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-service-overview)**. Select transfer service in BigQuery web console and fill the source and destination details and run it on-demand or schedule it on specified time interval.

[image]

Or simply run following gcloud command to achieve this

```
bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=[PROJECT_ID] --data_source=[DATA_SOURCE] --target_dataset=[DATASET] --display_name=[NAME] --params='[PARAMETERS]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it is not working for you, since it works perfectly for me.

```
projectFrom = 'project1'
datasetFrom = 'dataset1'
tableSearchString = 'test1'

projectTo = 'project2'
datasetTo = 'dataset2'

tables = bq.DataSet(projectFrom + ':' + datasetFrom).tables()

for table in tables:
  if tableSearchString in table.name.table_id:

    tableFrom = projectFrom + ':' + datasetFrom + '.' + table.name.table_id
    tableTo = projectTo + ':' + datasetTo + '.' + table.name.table_id

    !bq cp $tableFrom $tableTo
```

Try this in your notebook, since it works well for me. 
Just wondering, what is the error code that returns from your script?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help you.

```
    tables = source_dataset.list_tables()
    for table in tables:
        #print table.name
        job_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        dest_table = dest_dataset.table(table.name)
        source_table = source_dataset.table(table.name)
        if not dest_table.exists():
            job = self.bigquery_client.copy_table(job_id, dest_table, source_table)
            job.create_disposition = (google.cloud.bigquery.job.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
            job.begin()
            job.result()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the CLI:

```
bq ls src_dataset | grep TABLE | cut -f 3 -d ' ' | xargs -I {} bq cp src_dataset.{} dst_dataset.{}
```

First, get a list of table names from the source dataset, then copy them to the destination.

If you want to see the commands before executing them put an `echo` at the beginning:

```
bq ls src_dataset | grep TABLE | cut -f 3 -d ' ' | xargs -I {} echo bq cp src_dataset.{} dst_dataset.{}
```